# mongodb не стартует

Tags: linux, mongodb

ubuntu 18.

```
service mongodb status
● mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-07-01 00:29:17 EEST; 2s ago
     Docs: man:mongod(1)
  Process: 18670 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --unixSocketPrefix=${SOCKETPATH} --config ${CONF} $DAEMON_OPTS (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 18670 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jul 01 00:29:17 systemd[1]: Started An object/document-oriented database.
Jul 01 00:29:17 systemd[18670]: mongodb.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Jul 01 00:29:17 systemd[18670]: mongodb.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/mongod: Permission denied
Jul 01 00:29:17 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jul 01 00:29:17  systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

mongo ставил из пакетов 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mongodb/mongodb_3.6.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Comment: `sudo service mongodb start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не установленны зависимости для пакета. Нужно выполнить:

```
apt-get -f install
```

Permission denied возникает и в случае если линковщик не может найти библиотеку зависимости.

Проверить можно через `ldd /usr/bin/mongod`. Если ставили с репозитория вашего релиза ОС, то `apt-get -f install` решит зависимости.

Answer (score 0):

Написано ведь ясно:

> Permission denied

И тут только два варианта:

1. *mongodb.service* имеет право запускать только пользователь с правами root
2. В файле *mongodb.service* в параметре *ExecStart=* указан файл, у которого не выставлен атибут "исполняемый".

Comment: есть третий случай

Comment: @eri Если третий случай заключается в использовании флага *apt-get -f install* тогда - удачи! :-) Как говорят старые преферанасисты: "Риск - дело благородное! Особенно - при поносе" :-)

Comment: не во флаге апт, а в линковке на недостающие библиотеки. П.С. - у меня галочка :Р